# How to test instance variables using ".where" and ".where.not" methods in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to programming. Right now, I'm testing my products_controller using rspec. This products_controller has many instance variables and some of them use "where" method to get the necessary data.

I would like to know how to test code using ".where" and ".where.not" in controllers.

Could someone help me ?

**models/product.rb(association extracted)**

```
belongs_to :category, optional: true
belongs_to :user
has_many :product_images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @images = @product.product_images.limit(4)
  @products = @product.user.products.where.not(id: params[:id]).limit(6)
  @category_products = Product.where(category_id:@product.category).where.not(id: params[:id]).limit(6)
  @prev_item = @product.showPrevItem if @product.checkPrevItem
  @next_item = @product.showNextItem if @product.checkNextItem
end
```

**products_controller.spec.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do

    name                 {'アメリカンイーグルのTシャツ'}
    description          {'買ったばっかり'}
    category_id          {'1'}
    size                 {'M'}
    product_status       {'新品、未使用'}
    delivery_fee         {'着払い'}
    local                {'北海道'}
    lead_time            {'1~2日で発送'}
    price                {'300'}
    transaction_status   {'出品中'}

    user
    category
  end
end
```

**products_controller_spec.rb(incomplete)**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ProductsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #show' do
    it "renders the :show template" do
      product = create(:product)
      get :show, params: { id: product }
      expect(response).to render_template :show
    end

    it "assigns the requested product to @product" do
      product = create(:product)
      get :show, params: {id:product}
      expect(assigns(:product)).to eq product
    end

    it "populates an array of products" do
      product = create(:product)
      user = product.user
      products = create_list(:product, 3)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at these links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035668/testing-where-queries-in-rspec-rails
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763398/how-to-stub-an-active-record-relation-to-test-a-where-clause-with-rspec

Answer (score 1):

For example, on your `products` factory, you can pass the association to create all the products with the same user:

```
product = create(:product)
user = product.user
products = create_list(:product, 3, user: user)
```

Then you can test several things you consider relevant like the presence of the relationship:

```
get :show, params: { id: product }
expect(assigns(:products).size).to eq 3
```

the limit of the query:

```
products = create_list(:product, 10, user: user)
get :show, params: { id: product }
expect(assigns(:products).size).to eq 6
```

the non inclusion of product:

```
get :show, params: { id: product }
expect(assigns(:products)).not_to include(product)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was able to write the test code for all of the instance variables except for the last two. Could I ask for your advice again on how to write code for testing @prev_item and@next_item? They hold the following record each: **@prev_item = Product.where('id < ?', params[:id]).last and@next_item = Product.where('id > ?', [params:id]).first**